# What is "a barren dispute"?

Tags: vocabulary

What does "a barren dispute" mean?

I have looked up dictionaries for "barren" but I don't know what it means when conjoined with "dispute".

Comment: Please give context. I can guess the likely meaning, but without context it may be hard to explain.

Answer (score 1):

It is not an idiom, and a google search finds only a few examples of the combination of words.

"Barren" has a dictionary definition "empty of meaning or value."  A dispute may be fruitful if the disputants gain something from the dispute: perhaps they gain an understanding of another point of view or one of the disputants might change their opinion.

> I had a fruitful discussion about God with Spinoza, and I think we are closer to understanding each other's positions.

But a barren dispute is pointless and empty.  Nobody learns anything, nobody changes their opinion. It is just empty posturing:

> In recent years, papers on [lacunes](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/neuroscience/lacune) could be classified
> into two groups: [...] This
> **barren dispute** was perhaps unavoidable in that the
> lacunar concept had become rather dogmatic...

Neither side of the argument about lacunes listened to the points made by the other side.  They just became dogmatic.

Comment: I don't think the fact that each side doesn't listen to the other is the key feature of a barren dispute, although it is often present, rather that no satisfactory outcome is likely, e.g. arguments about the existence of unicorns, or how many angels can dance on the head of a pin : 'a barren dispute, a controversy about over-refined subtleties.' - Univ. of Notre Dame [History of Philosophy (28)](https://maritain.nd.edu/jmc/etext/hop28.htm) As in barren soil, nothing will grow.

Comment: It means it is "empty of meaning or value" - but it may have been unavoidable.

Comment: My reaction, also. Here *barren* means the same as *fruitless* (elsewhere, too).